# AmCharts Marker Color when negative

Tags: javascript, json, charts, amcharts

I am using amcharts 3, My example: http://jsfiddle.net/fbKSa/194/

The chart shows % Change of some random values, **negative! and positive!** (hence red and green.

There is a "marker" at the top (green box next to "Change in %") -> photo here:[image]

**Goal**: When I hover over any negative value this box should change it's color to RED , because the value next to it is negative (in this case -48.23%).

I have tried to add the following to no avail:

```
  lineColor: "#25DB25",
  fillColor: "#25DB25",
  negativeLineColor: "#c10d0d",
  negativeFillColors:  "#c10d0d",
  useDataSetColors: false,
  useNegativeColorIfDown: true
```

Documentation for "Cursor Settings" and "StockGraph":
https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ChartCursorSettings
https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#useNegativeColorIfDown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this answer here, in case someone else is wondering about the same.

This feature is available since version 3.20.1. You would need to set [`useMarkerColorForLabels`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/LegendSettings#useMarkerColorForLabels) to `true` in order for this to work:

```
"legendSettings": {
  "useMarkerColorForLabels":true
}
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fbKSa/218/).